# Reload another sentence with an click on my button

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on this little project, but I am stuck.
I want my program to load a sentence or word every time I push on a button.
I got it working once, but when I push my button again it does not reload a new word.

I tried to work with the page reloading, but that also does not work.

Can anyone help me so that when I push the button it automatically generates a new random word from my list? Keep in mind that I am very new to HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomSong;
}
var song = Array("song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6");
var randomSong = song[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.length)];
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction();">Moet er een atje worden gedaan? </button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: MOve `var randomSong = song[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.length)];` inside the function and the array to before the function

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="myFunction();">Moet er een atje worden gedaan?
</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>  function myFunction() {
    var song = Array("song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6");
    var randomSong = song[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.length)];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomSong;
  }  
</script>
```

If your randomSong variable should get a new value everytime you click the button, then it should be inside the function myFunction which executes on every click

EDIT: Also, moving the variable declarations outside the function will be more good, as we don't have to re-create the variables every time.

```
<script>
  var song = Array("song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6");
  var randomSong;
  function myFunction() {

    randomSong = song[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.length)];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomSong;
  }  
</script>
```

EDIT2: Adding internal styles as per the request.

```
<style>
  button { //selects the element with element name directly
    padding: 20px;
  }
  #demo { // selects the element with id
    font-size: 35px;
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

put this in your code

Comment: @mplungjan, while your comment may answer the question, giving a bit more descriptive answer can help the one who posted the question, though I appreciate your quick answer.

Comment: Sure. Still not really worth answering 5 times :)

Comment: You are correct, but I was not aware there was a comment, because I was busy phrasing the answer (to be more descriptive) as soon as the question was posted. sorry about that :)

Comment: @Tick20 Do you know how I could get the button to be bigger and the given text (song1, song2, etc) to be bigger. I can not figure it out.

Comment: @Josse, just add some css styling to your button, maybe padding. you can either add inline styling or internal styling or external, for now just update the <button style="padding: 20px".....

Comment: I have edited and added styles in the answer, have a look pls.

Comment: No problem, pls accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction();">Moet er een atje worden gedaan?</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  var song = Array("song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6");
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = song[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.length)];
  }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var randomSong = song[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.length)];
  console.log(randomSong);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randomSong;
}
var song = Array("song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6");
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction();">Moet er een atje worden gedaan? </button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```